# osx swift pass path with space as argument to shell script called by NSTask

Tags: macos, shell, swift, nstask

This is the code I can't get to work. If I remove the directory part with the space my shell script runs fine.

shell script simplified is : /usr/bin/find $1 -name *.txt

error with the space is binary operator expected

```
let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let path = bundle.pathForResource("doSimpleFind", ofType: "sh")

 let findTask = NSTask()
 let pipe = NSPipe()
 findTask.standardOutput = pipe

 // directory where to search from the script. testing the space in the name
 let constArgsString:String = "/Users/aUser/Library/Application\\ Support"
 //let constArgsString:String = "/Users/aUser/Library/"
 findTask.launchPath = path!
 findTask.arguments = [constArgsString]
 findTask.launch()
 findTask.waitUntilExit()
 let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
 let outputText:String = NSString(data: data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
 cmdTextResult.textStorage?.mutableString.setString(outputText)
```

Comment: This approach was the only way i was able to pass an argument to a .sh from NSTask. All other examples i've seen launches a command from arguments. But are unable to then pass an argument to the .sh script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSTask()` launches the process "directly" with the given arguments, without using a shell. Therefore it is not necessary to escape any
space or other characters in the launch arguments:

```
let constArgsString = "/Users/aUser/Library/Application Support"
```

But you have to handle arguments with spaces in your shell script correctly. In your example, `$1` needs to be enclosed in double quotes,
otherwise it might be passed as multiple arguments to the `find`
command:

```
/usr/bin/find "$1" -name "*.txt"
```

Comment: tested and worked. I tried the for c in "$@" but hadn't tried that without the "\ " in the path. I am surprised that the find command accepts a path with a space in this way, but glad it works. trying to reuse some old scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it complete you should obtain the folders path as follow:

```
let appSupportPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!.path
```

or

```
let libraryPath = FileManager.defaultManager.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!.path
```